# How to build boot2docker.iso from source?

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker

I'm trying to setup Docker on OSX not using the OSX App or Vagrant. I noticed boot2docker now supports the VMWare Guest Additions to mount directories. However the latest version including these changes hasn't been released yet. So how do I build a new boot2docker.iso file from the GitHub repository?

Boot2docker includes a documentation on how to do this: [BUILD.md](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md)

Unfortunately the documentations doesn't make sense to me. I'm not sure what I need to do to build that ISO file.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.3.0 and up, which supports the extensions and also mounting host volumes, has been released in the meantime (a litte over a day after your question).

It is available here: https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/releases